# Highcharts add image on export

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im using Highcharts with the export feature, from what I understand to add images to the chart I can use the renderer which works fine however I do not want the image (a logo) to appear on the chart in the app I want it to appear only on export, how would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions) object and then catch load event where you place renderer code.

```
exporting:{
                chartOptions:{
                    chart:{
                        events:{
                            load:function(){
                                this.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30)
                .add();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rLfj69b9/2/

Comment: How come it is not visible in chart but added in exported files? I want the same.

Comment: Im confused, in the scenario above, the image is added only for exported files. Let me know if you mean to add image on chart too.

Comment: No I want exactly the same. But I tried the same and image is showing up in my chart also.

Comment: Could you update my example with your code, because the demo (from post) works properly.

Comment: hi this example is not working if i try to dynamic set the position of the chart. e.g.            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function(event) {
                        var cwidth = document.getElementById('container').clientWidth;
                        var cheight = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;
                        this.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.pngg',(cwidth-80), (cheight-30), 50, 30).add();
                    }
                }        
            },

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net